# Implementing UITableViewController with Storyboard

Tags: swift, storyboard, interface-builder

I've just started my first iOS app (having just finished an OSX app). It's currently got 3 tabs where the first contains a UIView that shows a Google map and the other 2 are UITableViewControllers and I'm trying to set them up.

My storyboard looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF2E7.png

and the UITableViewController class like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF2E7.png#1

I have connected the class to my delegate and data properties of the UIViewController but I can't connect an outlet, am I off to a poor start here? Does anyone have a tutorial for starting out with the UITableViewController class with Swift?

Comment: Your table view controller needs to conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: Such that the class would begin with the following?

   `class SecondViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` My class won't let me do this for some reason.

Comment: `UITableViewController` already implements those, so you need to override the appropriate data source and delegate methods

Comment: Thank you for steering me in the right direction, with your help and using [link] (https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/) I managed to get it working the way I liked, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard class for `UITableViewController` looks something like the following code. Just make sure in interface builder you set the class of the table view controller to `SecondViewController` and make sure your cell identifier in interface builder matches the cell identifier from your class.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class SecondViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "some text"
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I only just figured it out myself but thank you so much for taking the time to respond! It ought to be a great resource for others :) Cheers

Comment: No problem. This answer is actually different than the tutorial you linked to. This shows how to make a UITableViewController, whereas that tutorial shows how to make a UITableView within a UIViewController. Use whichever suits your needs, but notice they are not exactly the same thing

Comment: I see, I'll have to have a closer look. For the moment I seem to have what I need. Thank you